# How to export space with comments in Confluence REST API?

Tags: confluence

I am using this REST URL to export a whole space:

```
/rest/api/content?spaceKey=TD&limit=50&expand=title,version,body.storage.value,body.view.value&os_authType=basic
```

However I can't find a way to include page comments in the response.

EDIT: I have found out how to get the comment but cannot get the comment body:

```
/rest/api/content?spaceKey=TD&limit=50&expand=title,version,body.storage.value,body.storage.content.children.comment,container,metadata.labels&os_authType=basic
```

The problem now comes with trying to expand the comment body. This URL:

```
/rest/api/content?spaceKey=TD&limit=50&expand=title,version,body.storage.value,body.view.value,body.storage.content.children.comment.body,body.storage.content.children.comment.version,container,metadata.labels&os_authType=basic
```

Gives this error:

```
{
    statusCode: 500,
    message: "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot recursively expand : body"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After extensive research I have concluded this is impossible.